# JMH - Benchmarking Neo4j

Tags: java, mysql, neo4j, benchmarking, microbenchmark

I am currently trying to benchmark 2 different implementations of a database model using JMH and one of them is Neo4j.

The problem I am facing is that the measured time is vastly different to the time shown in the Neo4j Browser.

Using JMH:

```
Benchmark             Mode  Cnt     Score   Error  Units
Neo4j_JDBC.run        avgt       2434.298          ms/op
NEO4j_EMBEDDED.run    avgt          0.316          ms/op
```

In the Neo4j Browser:

```
Started streaming 1 records after 2 ms and completed after 2 ms.
```

The query is the same, no matter if I take the embedded server or the remote one connected using JDBC.

JMH Code:

```
@Setup
    public void setup() throws SQLException {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:neo4j:bolt://localhost", "neo4j", "password");
    }

    @TearDown
    public  void  tearDown() throws SQLException {
        con.close();
    }


    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    @Measurement(iterations = 1, time = 1)
    @Fork(1)
    public void run() throws SQLException {
            String query = "query...";
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            st.executeQuery(query);    
    }
```

The implementation is taken straight from [the documentation](http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-jdbc/)

The opposite is the case for the second data model though, that is using a MySQL server.

There the 'real' execution speed in DataGrip (that is also using JDBC) is shown to be ~ 100ms and my benchmark shows around 1.6ms/ops.

Am I missing something in my configuration?

Is this even the correct way to benchmark different database systems with different models?

Any help is appreciated!

edit: I updated the JMH code to not measure the connection instantiation and now I get the following results when comparing Neo4j with MySQL:

```
Benchmark                 Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
MYSQL_JDBC.run            avgt        1.224          ms/op
Neo4j_JDBC.run            avgt       18.580          ms/op
```

The MySQL code is pretty much the same as above just with a different JDBC URL.

Execution-time in Datagrip for the MySQL query:

```
1 row retrieved starting from 1 in 301ms (execution: 202ms, fetching: 99ms)
```

Obviously the more often I execute it, the faster it is but the lowest it has been in Datagrip was 45ms. Not even close to the 1.2 ms/op I measured using JMH.

Is it maybe a caching issue? Or is it not measuring properly?

Answer (score 1):

You are also measuring the time that it takes to set up a connection to the database in JMH, while directly interacting with the database does not. Try refactoring the Connection into a field and set it before executing performance tests.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was a stupid mistake on my end! It did however only go down to 18.580 ms/op (that shows up as while the MySQL implementation (that should take 100ms+) shows as 1.3 ms/op. I updated the code in my post to furthe elaborate on this issue, especially the MySQL comparison